# My table get duplicated rows with Jquery Table Sorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, tablesorter

I have search field in my project, which uses `$.post` for getting the results for the search query.
My problem: When a user click on the search button it works correctly, however when a user click on the search button again, and then click on my thead columns jquery sorter duplicates it with the previous search shows in the table.

How can I solve this so my sorter function does not duplicate?

this is the Jquery code for the search button click.

```
     $(function () {
            $('#submitfloat').click(function () {
                $('#loading').show();
                setTimeout(function () { $("#loading").hide(); }, 800);
                var SubjectTypes = $('#SubjectTypes').val();
                var Teams = $('#Teams').val();
                var Companies = $('#Companies').val();
                var Consultants = $('#Consultants').val();
                var PlannedDates = $('#PlannedDates').val();
                var CompletedDates = $('#CompletedDates').val();
                var DateTypes = $('#DateTypes').val();
                var data = {
                    Subjectypes: SubjectTypes,
                    Companies: Companies,
                    Teams: Teams,
                    Consultants: Consultants,
                    PlannedDates: PlannedDates,
                    CompletedDates: CompletedDates,
                    DateTypes: DateTypes
                };

                var fromDate = $('#PlannedDates').val();
                var endDate = $('#CompletedDates').val();
                if (Date.parse(fromDate) > Date.parse(endDate)) {
                    jAlert("End date must be later than start date", "Warning");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $('#GoalcardSearchResult tbody').hide();
                    setTimeout(function () { $("#GoalcardSearchResult tbody").show(); }, 800);
                    $.post('@Url.Action("Search", "SearchNKI")', data, function (result) {

                        $("#GoalcardSearchResult tbody").empty();


                        result.forEach(function (goalcard) {

                            $("#GoalcardSearchResult tbody").append(
                                $('<tr/>', {
                                    click: function () {
                                        id = goalcard.Id;
                                        var url = '@Url.Action("AnswerForm", "AnswerNKI", new { id = "__id__"})';
                                        window.location.href = url.replace('__id__', id);


                                    },

                                    html: "<td>" + goalcard.Name + "</td><td>" + goalcard.Customer + "</td><td>" + goalcard.PlannedDate + "</td><td>" + goalcard.CompletedDate + "</td>"
                                }));
                        });
                        $("#GoalcardSearchResult").tablesorter();
                    });
                    return false; 
                }
            });
        });
```

Your help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing tablesorter has already been initialized before the user clicks on the sort button. In that case, replace this code:

```
$("#GoalcardSearchResult").tablesorter();
```

with this:

```
$("#GoalcardSearchResult").trigger('update');
```